# Microsoft CRM 2015 API and Cross domain support

Tags: cross-domain, cors, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

Does CRM 2015 support CORS or JSONP in any way? I'm trying to execute POST request from my web site to http://some/SomOrg/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/ContactSet url to create a new contact, but Chrome fails with :

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://Something' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

That looks legit as CRM doesn't return any CORS headers, but still is there a way to execute it? I've tried some URL parameters like '$callback' but they didn't help... MSDN also doesn't help too much...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not in CRM 2015 - but it's coming in the 2016 release

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309589(v=crm.8).aspx